# Find last row of inverse of a matrix, without calculating the inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to know if there is a way to calculate the last row of the inverse of a matrix $A$ without having to calculate $A^{-1}$, since inverting is notoriously expensive in computational terms.

Comment: Well, it's a system of $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns.  The product of the last row with the $i$th column is $0$ unless $i=n,$ when the product is $1$.

Comment: There's the formula for computing the inverse, $A^{-1}=\frac1{\det A}\mathrm{adj}A$. You can find the last row of $A^{-1}$ by considering the last row of $\mathrm{adj}A$. Do you consider that to be too expensive?

Comment: Yes, the expensive part is the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ is the last row of $A^{-1}$ then $$rA=[0,0,\dots,0,1].$$Solving that is the best you're going to do, since  finding the last row *is* finding a solution to that equation.

How much better is this than finding all of $A^{-1}$? Hmm. Since systems of linear equations are more typically written in the form $Ax=b$, note that the equation above is equivalent to $$A^Tr^T=[0,0,\dots,0,1]^T.$$So you need to row-reduce the "augmented matrix" $$[A^T|[0,0,\dots,0,1]^T].$$You find $A^{-1}$ by row-reducing the matrix $[A|I]$, which is clearly no more than $n$ times as much work; I tend to suspect it's considerably less than a factor of $n$, since most of the work in row-reducing either augmented matix involves manipulating the entries of $A$.

Hmm${}^2$: Finding the inverse of $A$ is equivalent to finding thhe inverse of $A^T$ and then taking the transpose. And in fact row-reducing $[A^T|I]$ is no worse than twice as expensive as row-reducing $[A|[0,0,\dots,0,1]^T]$, since (if $A$ is actually invertible) you perform exactly the same row operations but each one takes twice as long. So it seems to me that finding the last row of the inverse is at most a factor of $2$ better than finding the inverse..